# Running subqueries in pyspark using where or filter statement

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to run a subquery in pyspark. I see that it is possible using SQL statements. But is there any inherent support using "where" or "filter" operations?

Consider the test data frame :

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sqlContext = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate() 
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2),(4,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6)],schema=['sample','time'])
tst_sub = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2),(4,3),(1,4)],schema=['sample','time'])
#%% using where to query the df
tst.where(F.col('time')>4).show()
+------+----+
|sample|time|
+------+----+
|     1|   5|
|     1|   6|
+------+----+
```

Here you can see that the where function is working fine.
When I try to do the same using a subquery , like this:

```
#%% using where with subquery
tst.where(F.col('time')>F.max(tst_sub.select('time'))).show()
```

I get this error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 tst.where(F.col('time')>F.max(tst_sub.select('time'))).show()
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4744.12781922/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py
> in _(col)
> 42     def _(col):
> 43         sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
> ---> 44         jc = getattr(sc._jvm.functions, name)(col._jc if isinstance(col, Column) else col)
> 45         return Column(jc)
> 46     _.**name** = name
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4744.12781922/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in **call**(self, *args)    1246     1247     def **call**(self,
> *args):
> -> 1248         args_command, temp_args = self._build_args(*args)    1249     1250         command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4744.12781922/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in _build_args(self, *args)    1216     1217         args_command =
> "".join(
> -> 1218             [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])    1219     1220         return args_command, temp_args
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4744.12781922/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
> in (.0)    1216     1217         args_command = "".join(
> -> 1218             [get_command_part(arg, self.pool) for arg in new_args])    1219     1220         return args_command, temp_args
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4744.12781922/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_command_part(parameter, python_proxy_pool)
> 296             command_part += ";" + interface
> 297     else:
> --> 298         command_part = REFERENCE_TYPE + parameter._get_object_id()
> 299
> 300     command_part += "\n"
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.3.4-1.cdh6.3.4.p4744.12781922/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py
> in **getattr**(self, name)    1298         if name not in
> self.columns:    1299             raise AttributeError(
> -> 1300                 "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.**class**.**name**, name))    1301         jc =
> self._jdf.apply(name)    1302         return Column(jc)
>
> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

When I register the dataframes as table and perform a sql query, it works fine:

```
tst.createOrReplaceTempView("tst")
tst_sub.createOrReplaceTempView("tst_sub")
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM tst WHERE time>(SELECT(max(time)) FROM tst_sub)").show()
```

Is there any method to perform a subquery in pyspark on the dataframes directly using filter, where or any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect the max time into a numerical variable in Python before putting it in the filter:

```
tst.where(F.col('time') > tst_sub.select(F.max('time')).head()[0]).show()
+------+----+
|sample|time|
+------+----+
|     1|   5|
|     1|   6|
+------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Will there be any performance issue when I do the collect ? Are subqueries faster because it does not need this?

Comment: You're just collecting a single number, so performance shouldn't be an issue. But I prefer using subqueries because it doesn't require collect.

Comment: Exactly, I prefer to avoid collect too. In this example , the query is simple. But not sure if collect is always a good idea. So am searching for the syntax of using subqueries, without any sql type commands. any idea?

Comment: it's not possible to use subqueries with dataframe API. You need to use SQL API for subqueries.

Comment: Thanks, this was what i was lookin for. Can you please add this line in your answer? I will mark it as accepted.